# how to refresh index from another page

Tags: php, ajax, html

I have a simple grid showing some information about the items in the database. this is index.php.  When the user wants to edit one of the records they click on the link which opens another page (edit.php).  When they are finished editing I would like to find a way to refresh the index.php so it has the updated info. Is there a way to do this?

---

I found this and modified it, seems to work well.

```
function onFocus(){
    location.reload();
};


if (/*@cc_on!@*/false) { // check for Internet Explorer
    document.onfocusin = onFocus;
    document.onfocusout = onBlur;
} else {
    window.onfocus = onFocus;
    window.onblur = onBlur;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For refresh parent window from child window using javascript

```
 opener.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function onFocus(){
    location.reload();
};


if (/*@cc_on!@*/false) { // check for Internet Explorer
    document.onfocusin = onFocus;
    document.onfocusout = onBlur;
} else {
    window.onfocus = onFocus;
    window.onblur = onBlur;
}
```